# Use cumcount on pandas dataframe with a conditional increment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Consider the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A', 1],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 1],
        ['B', 0],
        ['A', 0],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 1]
    ], columns = ['key', 'cond'])
```

I want to find a cumulative (running) count (starting at 1) for each `key`, where we only increment if the previous value in the group had `cond == 1`. When appended to the above dataframe this would give

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A', 1, 1],
        ['A', 1, 2],
        ['B', 1, 1],
        ['B', 0, 2],
        ['A', 0, 3],
        ['A', 1, 3],
        ['B', 1, 2]
    ], columns = ['key', 'cond'])
```

Note that essentially the `cond` values of the last rows in each `key` group have no effect.

Just doing a simple `group` and `cumcount`

```
df.groupby('key').cumcount()
```

of course doesn't account for the `cond` value of the previous element. How can I take this into account?

**EDIT**

As some of the solutions below don't work on some edge cases, I will give a more comprehensive dataframe for testing.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A', 0],
        ['A', 1],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 1],
        ['B', 0],
        ['A', 0],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 1],
        ['B', 0]
    ], columns = ['key', 'cond'])
```

which when appending the true result should give

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A', 0, 1],
        ['A', 1, 1],
        ['A', 1, 2],
        ['B', 1, 1],
        ['B', 0, 2],
        ['A', 0, 3],
        ['A', 1, 3],
        ['B', 1, 2],
        ['B', 0, 3]
    ], columns = ['key', 'cond'])
```

Comment: There are only `1` and `0` values in column `cond` ?

Comment: Yes its just a flag.

Comment: Thank you, is possible first value is `0` per key?

Comment: Yes its possible the first value could be a 0.

Comment: OK, then need `bfill`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with combination of [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('key').cond.apply(
        lambda x: x.shift().fillna(1).cumsum()
).astype(int)
```

```
df
  key  cond  new
0   A     1    1
1   A     1    2
2   B     1    1
3   B     0    2
4   A     0    3
5   A     1    3
6   B     1    2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df['cnt'] = df[df["cond"]==1].groupby('key').cumcount()+1
df['cnt'] = df.groupby('key')['cnt'].fillna(method='bfill')
df
# =>   key  cond  cnt
#    0   A     1  1.0
#    1   A     1  2.0
#    2   B     1  1.0
#    3   B     0  2.0
#    4   A     0  3.0
#    5   A     1  3.0
#    6   B     1  2.0
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed "previous"

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive: Fixed now (and probably faster than `apply` :P )

Comment: Two groupby calls? Yeah, I dunno.

Comment: This is faster on my dataset than the @CallCentreExecutive solution, but fails when for a given `key` all the `cond` values are 0 and also if the final `cond` value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom lambda function with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for previous values, replace first `NaN` by back filling if possible first value is `0` per key and last [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with convert to `int`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('key')['cond'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().bfill().cumsum()).astype(int)

print (df)
  key  cond  new
0   A     1    1
1   A     1    2
2   B     1    1
3   B     0    2
4   A     0    3
5   A     1    3
6   B     1    2
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the first `cond` value in a group is 0. In this case it starts at 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @rwolst - So need always sart from 1, if first is `1` or `0` ?

Comment: Yep, always start from 1. Then if we observe a `cond=1`, the next row in the group will have an updated count.

Comment: @rwolst - Then need coldspeed solution.