# Pandas: Count iterating string occurrences over columns & rows with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, countif

I have a dataset of academic journals. The variable `Top Journal` is a dummy that equals 1 if the paper was published in a top-ranked journal.
`Publication Month` is the numerical month in which the paper was published. `author1`, `author2` etc. are the authors who wrote the specific paper in this row.

For each author, I want to count the number of prior publications in top journals. Thus, I want to count all previous occurrences of his/her name in one of the columns `authorX`, but only when the paper was published in a top journal.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Top Journal': [1,0,1],
                  'Publication Year': [2020, 2020, 2020],
                  'Publication Month': [8,8,7],
                  'author1': ['Hendren, Nathaniel', 'Backus, Matthew','Enke, Benjamin'],
                  'author2': ['Sprung-Keyser, Ben', 'Blake, Thomas', 'Hendren, Nathaniel'],
                  'author3': [None,'Larsen, Brad', None ]},
                 index = ['UID1', 'UID2', 'UID3'])
```

Output should look like this:

```
 Top     Publication Publication    author1           author2           author3    previous_publications1  previous_publications2  previous_publications3
Journal     Year       Month
  1         2020        8      Hendren, Nathaniel  Sprung-Keyser, Ben     None             1                      0                       None
  0         2020        8       Backus, Matthew     Blake, Thomas      Larsen, Brad        0                      0                        0
  1         2020        7        Enke, Benjamin    Hendren, Nathaniel     None             0                      0                       None
```

Important: If the author name is mentioned in `author1` once, it could appear in any other position (e.g. `author6`) in another observation.

The number of previous top journal publications are supposed to be shown in new columns `previous_publications1`, `previous_publications2`, where the numbers refer to respective authors. Thus, author1 of the first paper (Hendren, Nathaniel) counts a higher number of publications than when Hendren, Nathaniel appears the second time in the third row.

Comment: Can you kindly post your expected output?

Comment: Of course, sorry. For example, because only "Hendren, Nathaniel" appears in another top journal, for the first three rows the additional columns would look like this:
`previous_publications1`: 1 0 0
`previous_publications2`: 0 0 0
`previous_publications3`: None 0 None

Comment: Can you do `df.to_dict()` assuming a dataframe called `df` as well as df.index and copy and paste the code into your question?

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Top Journal': [1,0,1],
                  'Publication Year': [2020, 2020, 2020],
                  'Publication Month': [8,8,7],
                  'author1': ['Hendren, Nathaniel', 'Backus, Matthew','Enke, Benjamin'],
                  'author2': ['Sprung-Keyser, Ben', 'Blake, Thomas', 'Hendren, Nathaniel'],
                  'author3': [None,'Larsen, Brad', None]},
                 index = ['UID1', 'UID2', 'UID3'])
```

The format of your `author` columns makes `wide_to_long` a good choice as you can use `author` as the stubname to bring all three author columns into one, so that you can take cumulatively count how many previous publications there were; but, in order to use `cumcount`, we needed the relevant data in one column. From there transform it back to original format with a "long-to-wide" using `unstack(3)` to put the fourth index column ('author #') into the column headers. Then you get rid of the multiindex and have the original column names with `df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns]`, but first the `author #` column names have to be strings with `.rename({1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3'}, axis=1)`:

---

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='author', i=['Top Journal', 'Publication Year', 'Publication Month'], j='author #')
        .sort_values(['Publication Year', 'Publication Month']))
df['previous_publications'] = df.groupby('author').cumcount()
df = df[~df['author'].isnull()].unstack(3).rename({1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3'}, axis=1).fillna('None')
df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns]
df
Out[1]: 
                                                           author1  \
Top Journal Publication Year Publication Month                       
0           2020             8                     Backus, Matthew   
1           2020             7                      Enke, Benjamin   
                             8                  Hendren, Nathaniel   

                                                           author2  \
Top Journal Publication Year Publication Month                       
0           2020             8                       Blake, Thomas   
1           2020             7                  Hendren, Nathaniel   
                             8                  Sprung-Keyser, Ben   

                                                     author3  \
Top Journal Publication Year Publication Month                 
0           2020             8                  Larsen, Brad   
1           2020             7                          None   
                             8                          None   

                                                previous_publications1  \
Top Journal Publication Year Publication Month                           
0           2020             8                                     0.0   
1           2020             7                                     0.0   
                             8                                     1.0   

                                                previous_publications2  \
Top Journal Publication Year Publication Month                           
0           2020             8                                     0.0   
1           2020             7                                     0.0   
                             8                                     0.0   

                                                previous_publications3  
Top Journal Publication Year Publication Month                          
0           2020             8                                     0.0  
1           2020             7                                     NaN  
                             8                                     NaN
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - it works wonderfully. I very much appreciate it!!

Comment: Hi David, `cumcount` right now counts all previous instances of the author name, regardless of whether the dummy `Top Journal` has a value of 1 or 0. I tried to fix it, but cannot succeed. A similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018739/use-cumcount-on-pandas-dataframe-with-a-conditional-increment

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Amongst other things, I tried: 
`df['previous_publications'] = df[df["Top Journal"]==1].groupby('author').cumcount()`
But this of course results in a `0` for all instances, in which an author has participated in a `Top Journal = 0`.

Comment: fixed it using `df['previous_publications'] = df.groupby('author').top_journal.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())`